# Why is $2^{n+1}\cdot\frac12$ equal to $2^n$ and not $1^{n+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to multiply $2^{n+1}$ by $\frac{1}{2}$.

The textbook says that I should end up with $2^n$.

To me, it seems like it should become $\frac{2^{n+1}}{2}$, and you should be left with $1^{n+1}$.

Comment: Do you know that $2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}$? Then $2^{n+1}\cdot 2^{-1}=2^n$.

Comment: and $2^{n+1}=2^n\times2$ ?     (note:  $2^{n+1}\times 1/2^{n+1}=1^{n+1})$

Comment: try with some small actual values for $n$

Comment: $\dfrac{a^{n}}{b} \neq \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n = \dfrac{a^n}{b^n}$

Comment: You know that $1^{n+1} = 1$ always. And you know then $a\times \frac 12 = 1$ means $a = 2$.  And you know $2^n \ne 2$ (unless $n =1$).  So you *should* know that *can't* be right.  And if you tried a value ... say $n = 3$ you'd know that $ {2^3}\cdot \frac 12 = 8\cdot \frac 12=4$ and $2^3 \cdot\frac 12 \ne 1^3 = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac {a^k}{b} \ne (\frac ab)^k$

$\frac {a^k}{b} = \frac {\overbrace{a\cdot a\cdot....\cdot a}^{k\text{ times}}}{b}=\frac ab\cdot (\overbrace{a\cdot a\cdot....\cdot a}^{k-1\text{ times}})=\frac ab a^{k-1}$

And $2^{n+1}= \underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot ....2}_{n+1\text{ times}}=\underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot ....2}_{n\text{ times}}\cdot 2= 2^n\cdot 2$ so

$2^{n+1} \cdot \frac 12 = (2^n\cdot 2)\cdot \frac 12 = 2^n$

Post-script:

This leads to the famous identity that most here are taking as so basic they forget that it has to be learned a first time:

$\frac {a^k}{a^m} = \frac {\underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{k\text { times}}}{\underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{m\text { times}}}=\frac {\underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{m\text { times}}\cdot \underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{k-m\text { times}}}{\underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{m\text { times}}}=\frac {\underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{m\text { times}}}{\underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{m\text { times}}}\cdot \underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{k-m\text { times}}=\underbrace{a\cdot... a\cdot}_{k-m\text { times}}=a^{k-m}$.

In this case $2^{n+1} \cdot \frac 12 = \frac {2^{n+1}}{2^1} = 2^{(n+1) -1} = 2^n$.

.....

But do try it for a few values of $n$.

$n=1$ then $2\cdot \frac 12 = 1 = 2^0$.

$n=2$ then $4 \cdot \frac 12 = 2 = 2^1$

$n=3$ then $8 \cdot \frac 12 = 4 = 2^2$

$n=4$ then $16\cdot \frac 12 = 8 = 2^3$.

.....etc.....

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying $2^{n + 1}$ by $\frac{1}{2}$ will yield $\frac{2^{n+1}}{2}$

Recall from indices, the rule: 
$\frac{x^{a}}{x^{b}}$ = $x^{a - b}$, where $x ≠ 0$. Then, we have

$2^{(n +1) - 1}$
$ = 2^{n + 1 - 1} $
$ = 2^n $ ...Ans.

Comment: Please use {} instead of () to get the whole term as exponent.

Comment: You were missing a closing bracket ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is $$\frac{2^{n+1}}{2}=2^{n+1-1}=2^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac{1}{2} = 2^{-1}$. Multiplying different powers of the same base gives you a product equal to the base raised to the sum of the powers. Thus, $\frac{1}{2} \times 2^{n + 1} = 2^{-1} \times 2^{n + 1} = 2^{n + 1 - 1} = 2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac 12 =2^{-1}$$
so:

$$2^{n+1}\cdot \frac12 =2^{n+1}\cdot 2^{-1}=2^{n+1-1}=2^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Rule of power: if you have two powers $a^b$ and $a^c$ and you want to multiply each other you obtain $a^{b+c}$. Now you have to write $1/2$ as $2$ power and this is $2^{-1}$. So: $2^{n+1}\cdot 2^{-1}=2^{n+1-1}=2^n$.